# Is certification required to conduct runways repairs?

Tags: faa-regulations, runways

I know that you need a certain certification to fix a plane, but are you required to have a certification to fix a runway?  Or can anyone with the proper equipment be paid to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you do not require any certification to fix a runway/taxiway, and anyone with a proper equipment can do that. But to facilitate the process, the FAA has published a few checklists which have to be filled while doing this repair job. These checklists can be found [Here](http://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/runway_construction/). FAA also provides assistance in guiding the construction jobs and identifying risks, the link to which is in the same website as mentioned above.

Comment: Indeed no formal certification, but with the amount of problems I have the feeling you could run into with that checklist I would imagine the companies willing to take on this type of job would probably have experience with it. It seems pretty well defined.